# Выделение одной строки

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток, пожалуйста напомните как сделать чтобы выделялась только одна строка в таблице. никак найти не могу.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaFX:**

```
tableview.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
```

**Swing:**

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

Comment: Спасибо что напомнили. Искренне благодарен.